# All attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed, returning an empty token

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

What I need help with / What I was wondering
tfds.load failure

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.load('glue/sst2', download=True, try_gcs=True, split="validation")
```

```
Stack trace
2021-01-09 10:57:42.393771: E tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/curl_http_request.cc:614] The transmission of request 0x7fcf41a30f60 (URI: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token) has been stuck at 0 of 0 bytes for 61 seconds and will be aborted. CURL timing information: lookup time: 0.001158 (No error), connect time: 0 (No error), pre-transfer time: 0 (No error), start-transfer time: 0 (No error) 2021-01-09 10:57:42.397383: W tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/google_auth_provider.cc:184] All attempts to get a Google authentication bearer token failed, returning an empty token. Retrieving token from files failed with "Unavailable: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 42 meaning 'Operation was aborted by an application callback', error details: Callback aborted". Retrieving token from GCE failed with "Failed precondition: Error executing an HTTP request: libcurl code 6 meaning 'Couldn't resolve host name', error details: Couldn't resolve host 'metadata'". 2021-01-09 10:58:46.099418: E tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/curl_http_request.cc:614] The transmission of request 0x7fcf3304b4e0 (URI: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/tfds-data/o/datasets%2Fglue?fields=size%2Cgeneration%2Cupdated) has been stuck at 0 of 0 bytes for 61 seconds and will be aborted. CURL timing information: lookup time: 0.000995 (No error), connect time: 0 (No error), pre-transfer time: 0 (No error), start-transfer time: 0 (No error) 2021-01-09 11:00:01.098669: E tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/curl_http_request.cc:614] The transmission of request 0x7fcf3304b4e0 (URI: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/tfds-data/o/datasets%2Fglue?fields=size%2Cgeneration%2Cupdated) has been stuck at 0 of 0 bytes for 61 seconds and will be aborted. CURL timing information: lookup time: 0.00099 (No error), connect time: 0 (No error), pre-transfer time: 0 (No error), start-transfer time: 0 (No error) 2021-01-09 11:02:05.646245: E tensorflow/core/platform/cloud/curl_http_request.cc:614] The transmission of request 0x7fcf33290910 (URI: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/tfds-data/o/datasets%2Fglue?fields=size%2Cgeneration%2Cupdated) has been stuck at 0 of 0 bytes for 61 seconds and will be aborted. CURL timing information: lookup time: 0.001604 (No error), connect time: 0 (No error), pre-transfer time: 0 (No error), start-transfer time: 0 (No error)
```

What I've tried so far
I use VPN, but It was useless at the time

It would be nice if...
Could we have done anything to make things better (documentation, etc.)?

Environment information
(if applicable)

```
Operating System: mac os 10.15.7
Python version: 3.7.9
tensorflow-datasets version: 4.2.0
tensorflow version: 2.4.0
tensorflow-metadata version: 0.26.0
```

Comment: see  in detail
 : https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/2929

Answer (score 3):

### Update

- system information

  - MacOS 12.5.1
  - Python 3.9
  - tensorflow 2.9.1
  - tensorflow-datasets 4.6.0
- Solution

```
from tensorflow_datasets.core.utils import gcs_utils
gcs_utils._is_gcs_disabled = True

tfds.load('glue/sst2', data_dir='path/to/somewhere', try_gcs=False)
```

- Check [#807](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/807#issuecomment-514872319) for more information, just a little bit simplify.

### Old

If you are in the mainland of China, GCS cannot be accessed inside thanks to firewalls.

But datasets(i tried `MNIST`, `COCO`) can be downloaded without GCS authetication. Just change `_is_gcs_disabled = True` as stated in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/807#issuecomment-704238147).

Comment: Good job. It works.